# GRPC connectivity issue with Azure App Service from local post man?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, grpc, azure-virtual-network, azure-appservice, grpc-web

I have GRPC application which I have created and deployed from visual studio to azure app service.
OS # Linux
Azure Service plan is # S1
[image]

Network Configuration #
[image]

On the App settings tab, add the following app settings to your application:
Name = HTTP20_ONLY_PORT
Value = 8585

when we try to run from post mane with azure app service URL #

[image]

we are not able connect GRPC.

Comment: Are you using .NET, and if so, which version?

Comment: we are using .net 6

Comment: for https calls change to [this](https://i.imgur.com/9oiCiYg.png)

Comment: not sure what is this ? mean here

Comment: Enable TLS to invoke the method over a secured connection.

Comment: Azure Web App URL is Secured one.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to create this project.

After creating the gRPC web app, it was deployed to Azure App Service. I am able to see the output in Postman.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using GrpcService2.Services;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "To communicate with gRPC, use the client.");
app.Run();
```

**GreeterService.cs**:

```cs
using Grpc.Core;
using GrpcService2;
namespace GrpcService2.Services
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**greet.proto**:

```cs
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService2";
package greet;
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

After running the gRPC app, I copied the following HTTPS URL, as it is a secure connection.

[image]

I enabled TLS by clicking the lock symbol in Postman, as shown below.

[image]

In the Azure Web App, under Environment Variables and App Settings, I set the following value:

`Name=HTTP20_ONLY_PORT   Value=5243`

As shown below.

[image]

Ensure that your values are as follows:

[image]

I successfully deployed the app to Azure through Visual Studio.

The Azure Web App URL is a secure connection, so you need to enable TLS as shown below.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]